# ICMP Destination Unreachable (Port unreachable)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables

I receive ICMP messages when transmitting UDPs. Two VBoxs (Ubuntu 18.04) transmit UDP to a central node (also VBox). All configured as Bridge. The central node, receives the UDP correctly but my doubt is why the edge nodes receive the ICMP? I've check the timestamp from the transmitted and received packet and they are the same (from the each pair of UDP-ICMP). My goal is:

1. avoid the ICMP (Destination Unreachable (Port unreachable))
2. The central node can forward the received UDP to the rest of nodes (i.e. from .60 to .63).

[image]